# .Net Windows Form Client. Capturing Request/Response SOAP from ASMX webservice

Tags: winforms, soap, asmx

before i decided to post this question i went thru several articles and questions in here... none of those seem to be a solution for me.... or i am doing something wrong.

I went thru this article, suggested in this site
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38986/Trace-SOAP-Request-Response-XML-with-TraceExtensio?msg=4152902#xx4152902xx

that's not working. Not even the source code i downloaded.

then i found this other article...

http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx

This is simple.
I have a client (winform)... interacts with a webservice i have no control over, and i need to be able to capture the soap request and response. i followed like 5 tutorials so far, soapextensions, soapattributes, etc, etc... nothing seems to work for me. i have modified app.config, done everything by the book... nothing.

Question... Does anyone have a WORKING example of this? the two examples i found don't work :)

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using tracing in the config file as described in the MSDN articles [How to: Configure Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) and [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)?

Comment: But what if the response stream is GZipped?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a "Service Reference" instead of a "Web Reference" then see WCF Tracing.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP extensions need to be registered on the service side (that's why all posts asking you to do configuration inside web.config).

If you want to print out the SOAP messages inside your WinForms client, you will have to call web service in the "raw" way,

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2006/05/making-raw-web-service-calls-with.html

@James demonstrates System.NET tracing, which is another way to see the SOAP messages in an external log file, but that's only useful for troubleshooting, as you won't receive the tracing data inside your client.